# What does a red background for filename mean in an Image Texture node?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

Normally the image file name is black on light gray.  Here, it is red.  What does that mean?

I know it's *not* the file missing. The scene renders just fine, with the image texture doing what it's supposed to.

I'm using 2.70, Cycles, making an elaborate animation with complex materials.

Comment: Maybe fixed with 2.72?

Comment: @DarenW Could it be that you plugged in a UVMap that is no longer available? I remember something like this vaguely but can't reproduce at the moment.

Comment: @stacker That's not it...

Comment: @DarenW Could you upload a example .blend?